# Vue to don't assign active class ever

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, bootstrap-vue

I am using Bootstrap Vue and I have a dropdown like so

```
      <b-nav-item-dropdown right>
        <b-dropdown-item class="company-menu-text" :to="{ name: 'locationlist' }" exact>Lokaliteter</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item class="company-menu-text" @click="logout">Logg ut</b-dropdown-item>
      </b-nav-item-dropdown>
```

where Vue Router nicely takes me to the locationlist when I click there as expected. Not so nice is that the `active` class is then assigned to the dropdown item. I would like this not to happen ever. The best I have been able to get is to limit it with `exact`. How can I make sure that the `active` class is **NEVER** assigned to this dropdown item?

Versions I'm using of the relevant packages:

```
"bootstrap": "4.1.1",
"bootstrap-vue": "2.0.0-rc.11",
"vue": "2.5.16",
"vue-router": "3.0.1",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hack that got the look I wanted was to modify the dropdown-item CSS:

```
.dropdown-item.active, .dropdown-item:active {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

but I still think that there must be a solution so that I don't set links to active. Because I have links other places than just in this dropdown menu, and don't think writing a ton of CSS is the right answer.